# Exporting collections

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

have select like

```
select trn_dt,collect(ac_no)
from transactions
where rownum < 1000
group by trn_dt
```

i'm doing it in SQL Navigator. But i can't export results!
Table collect(ac_no) is not exported. Is there any way out?

Comment: Doesn't this SQL statement generate a `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The COLLECT function returns a collection datatype, not a "simple" datatype.  Probably SQL Navigator's export cannot handle this.  You might want to use LISTAGG (11G) or WM_CONCAT to return a comma-delimited string instead.